# (Phonegap, iOS) when focus on input[type=text], "Resetting plugins due to page load" appears and page breaks

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, plugins, input

I am testing my Phonegap(cordova) app on iPhone 6(not the emulator)
When it comes to focusing on

```
<input type='text' />
```

**"Resetting plugins due to page load"** appears in terminal
and page breaks.. meaning buttons don't function well, pinch zoom in gets enabled.. etc

After googling,, i am guessing it's about
page change issue.. but I couldn't find the exact solution for my case
where it's related to

```
<input type='text' />
```

Can anyone help?